# Align first line TextView by bottom of view

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I have some view and `TextView`. TextView can have one or more lines.
I want align first line TextView to bottom of some view:

[image]

[image]

UPD: Now I use manual marginTop for TextView:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_thumb_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
...
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dips8"
            android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_thumb_group"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="message" />
```

Comment: post your code then say what is the problem?

Comment: @Hamid Shatu, I think code don't help for this. But simple: now I set for TextView android:layout_marginTop with some dips to align TextView with target position. I just picked this margin visually.

Comment: @Hamid Shatu update first post.

Answer (score 0):

Align the top of the TextView with the bottom of the LinearLayout and give the TextView a negative top margin that is equal to the text size:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_thumb_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
...
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dips8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_thumb_group"
        android:layout_below="@id/user_thumb_group"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="message" />
```

Comment: hm, are you sure that sp = dp?

Comment: You're right, they will be different if the user changes the font size settings (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/213817). So you should probably use sp for the marginTop as well.